# Trouble with output of Reduce as a root object for a 3d Plot

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, code-review

I am trying to find the value of $r_0$ using $L^2=\frac{{r_0}^3 f'({r_0})}{2 f({r_0})-{r_0} f'({r_0})}$ and making a 3d plot with the help of the code given below:

```
$Assumptions = Thread[{l, L, Q, r0, rp} > 0];
f[r_] := 1 - (2 M)/r + Q^2/r^2 + r^2/l^2;
M = rp/2 (1 + Q^2/rp^2 + rp^2/l^2);
Veff[r_] = f[r] (L^2/r^2 + 1)
eqn = L^2 == (r0^3 f'[r0])/(2 f[r0] - r0 f'[r0]) // Simplify;
sol = Reduce[eqn, r0][[2, 2, 1]] // ToRules;
\[Lambda][Q_, rp_] = 
  Block[{l = 1, L = 20}, 
    1/2 Sqrt[(r0 f'[r0] - 2 f[r0]) Veff''[r0]] /. sol] // Simplify;
Plot3D[Log[100, (\[Lambda][Q, rp] + 1)], {Q, 0, 1.2}, {rp, 0, 1}]
```

which gives me root objects as output instead of algebraic expressions.
I tried `ToRadicals`as discussed in other related answers but it didn't work for me.
The resulting 3d plot is also blank.
How to solve this problem?
[Reference paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/JHEP08(2022)153.pdf) (page 8)

Comment: The `Root` objects are roots of 6th order polynomials, where no general solution in terms of radicals exists

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but then how can I express $r_0$ in terms of $L$ as stated in the reference paper? Is there any possibility to do that?

Comment: In the paper they say, just above (3.10), that (3.9) "can be used to express $r_0$ in terms of $L$", but they don't give any expression or even imply it's analytic in terms of radicals ;-)

Comment: @HansOlo that's what troubles me. Even if I use the root object as input, I don't get the desired 3D plot as given in Figure 6, for the massive particles, instead I get a blank plot.

Comment: All of your variables have positive values. This knowledge should be shared with Mathematica. By using `$Assumptions = Thread[{l, L, Q, r0, rp} > 0];` the assumptions will automatically be available to any function that uses the option `Assumptions`.  After defining `$Assumptions`, simplify the equation, `eqn = L^2 == (r0^3 f'[r0])/(2 f[r0]-r0 f'[r0])//Simplify;`If you are having trouble plotting, show the code that you used for the plot.

Comment: @BobHanlon thank you for the valuable comment. I used your advice and edited my code above. I am still getting a blank plot when I use the root object as the solution for `r0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Assumptions = Thread[{l, L, Q, r0, rp} > 0];

f[r_] := 1 - (2 M)/r + Q^2/r^2 + r^2/l^2;
M = rp/2 (1 + Q^2/rp^2 + rp^2/l^2);
Veff[r_] = f[r] (L^2/r^2 + 1);
eqn = L^2 == (r0^3 f'[r0])/(2 f[r0] - r0 f'[r0]) //
   Simplify;

sol = {Reduce[eqn, r0] // Simplify // ToRules}[[2 ;; 3]];

λ[Q_, rp_] = Block[{l = 1, L = 20},
    1/2 Sqrt[(r0 f'[r0] - 2 f[r0]) Veff''[r0]] /. 
     sol] // Simplify;

Column[
 Plot3D[Evaluate@Log[100, (# + 1)],
    {Q, 0, 6/5}, {rp, 0, 1},
    PlotPoints -> 60,
    MaxRecursion -> 3,
    ClippingStyle -> None,
    WorkingPrecision -> 15,
    AxesLabel ->
     {Q, rp, 
      Rotate[HoldForm@Log[100, λ[Q, rp] + 1], 90 Degree]},
    ImageSize -> 480] & /@
  λ[Q, rp]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the illuminating answer. It helped me getting started. The plot is very close to the Figure 6 on page 8 of the reference paper. There are minor differences, which maybe due to the difference in the plot range.